# Comments aren't displayed on Area 51 if the comment section has to be expanded

Tags: bug, comments, area-51

I commented on a question on Area 51 two hours ago. The question having received over 5 comments, one has to expand the comment section to view all comments. However, mine does not show up:

[image]

Someone replied to my comment and it also doesn't show up, either to them or to me.

Link to the question: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113814/medical-sciences/113832#113832

Comment: Did you insult anyone or was the comment in any other way inappropriate and therefor possible removed due to moderation/flags?

Comment: @rene no, all comments were courteous.

Comment: Guess they never expected any sample question on Area 51 to have more than 5 comments. (So nobody bothered to ever test it.)

Comment: @rene it's borked for sure, there is an AJAX code that should run and fetch all comments. In Area 51 it simply does not exist, I checked with Network tab open. (Probably they forgot to add that part to the old codebase.)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The question was deleted?

Comment: @Narusan Yes, I deleted it: too many downvotes, and Stack Exchange developers didn't seem interested to implement Bumblebee's fix.

Comment: Pity. I couldn’t even read the discussion between you and DoctorWhom.

Comment: @Narusan I addressed their comments, so it's okay.  "Now that the negative vote has been pulled, it's all good to stay! It does overrepresent a little but not a big deal. I just wanted to be sure we save downvotes for the things seriously needing downvoting. BUT perhaps can you put a little bit in the question stem as to what oil injections are, like we often do in the intro to the actual questions? Otherwise it seems a little out of the blue - even I've never heard of it! – Doctor Whom ↵ Oct 1 at 2:58". I couldn't read the other comments because of the issue I raised in this question.

Comment: Feel free to post other questions. The magnitude of tendinopathy questions you have at Health.SE might also be a better fit for MedSci because they are a lot more academic. But then again, we still haven’t found a great way to differentiate.

Comment: @Narusan I have posted the maximum amount of questions, i.e. 5. Yes to be honest in my mind MedSci = Health.SE - people who have no clue on how to think about medical issues (e.g., never read a medical research article). And the way Health.SE was managed was pretty much a disaster; amongst other things it pissed off a few users who had the ability to contribute.

Comment: @Narusan ha, i have the same problem, and I also asked 5 questions already

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt you seem to be very angry on the way it's moderated... Why do you think the new one is just the same?

Comment: @Ooker not angry, but in disagreement :-) As a reminder, many questions, answers and comments of mine were removed by the moderation. Both MedSci and Health.SE are about medical questions.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yeah I still not really fully understand on how comments and answers are considered to be bad, but I think it might be because I'm don't have enough knowledge on medical, so I don't have comments on that. I do share your disagreement though. But questions are removed too? What gives?

Comment: @Ooker roomba removed the questions.

Comment: Ah right. I saw your discussion on the roomba on Softrec too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the issue

[image]

They are checking whether the text **more comment** or **more announcement** is present there using `indexOf > -1`.

But the actual wording is **more improvement**.

So, both the conditions become false and hence the if won't execute. That if contains the code to fetch more comments and since it doesn't execute, the comments won't load at all.

They can add one more check as

```
if ($(this).text().indexOf("more comment") > -1 ||
    $(this).text().indexOf("more announcement") > -1 ||
    $(this).text().indexOf("more improvement") > -1) {
```

Recently Robert announced that they changed the wording from comment. so if the word comment is no longer used, they can remove that check too.

Comment: Good job, pet!!

Comment: my pet is smart :-) he can smell any issues

Comment: So is this fixed yet?

Comment: @Ooker No, one of your posts has the same problem